# Wrongly calculated integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, bounds-of-integration

> Calculate 
>   $$\iiint_V \frac{1}{(x+y+z)^3} \, dV$$
>   Where $V$ is the volume bounded by the planes 
>   $$\{4x + 3z = 12, 4x + z = 4, 4y + 3z = 12, 4y + z = 4, z = 0\}$$

I've used simple coordinates change to $z$ such that:
$z=4-w$

So the boundris are a little clearer, from here I calculated that the boundaries are:
$$0\le w \le4$$

$$ \frac{w}{4} \le x,y\le \frac{3w}{4} $$

with $dz=-dw$

So from here the integral and the boundaries look like this:

$$
\int_0^4
\int_{w/4}^{3w/4}
\int_{w/4}^{3w/4}\frac{-dx\,dy\,dw}{(x+y+4-w)^3}
$$

But everywhere I tried to even just numerically calcualte this integral I was told the integral is divergent. I know the Boundaries are compact, it's a tilted upside down pyramid but it seems I did a mistake along the way. What do?

Comment: What are the conditions $4x + 3z = 12, 4x + z = 4, 4y + 3z = 12, 4y + z = 4, z = 0$?

Comment: boundries to the integral

Comment: It looks like the region of interest is the intersection of two triangular prisms, one rotated 90 degrees from the other. I would suggest you recompute without the change of coordinates.

Comment: How could $$\begin{cases}4x+3z=12 \\ 4x+z=4\end{cases},$$ and $z=0$ if the former implies that $z=4$?

Comment: These are not holding simultaneously, @Crosby. These are the separate boundary planes ...

Comment: Oh, okay. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region is a square pyramid with the vertex offset from the base.

i.e. $(1,1,0), (1,3,0), (3,3,0), (3,1,0), (0,0,4)$

We would could solve this by breaking up the integral into regions that are easier to integrate.

If we make a change of coordinates like

$x = u - \frac 12 z\\
y = v - \frac 12 z\\
z = z$

Then our boundaries become

$4u + z = 12\\
4u -z = 4\\
4v + z = 12\\
4v - z = 4\\
z = 0$

Moving our vertices to something centered over the base. $(1,1,0), (1,3,0), (3,3,0), (3,1,0), (2,2,4)$

The integrand: $(x+y+z) = (u+v)$

The jacobain $\det \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&-\frac 12\\0&1&\frac 12\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} = 1$

$\int_0^4\int_{1+\frac{z}{4}}^{3-\frac {z}{4}}\int_{1+\frac{z}{4}}^{3-\frac {z}{4}} \frac {1}{(u+v)^3}\ du\ dv\ dz$

Comment: Looks fantastic, can you explain your motivation behind this specific change of coordinates?

Comment: I was looking for something that would move this vertex from not over the base in (x,y) coordinates into something that would be in (u,v) coordinates.  The center of the base is (2,2,0) in (x,y) coordinates.  So, I am looking for a nice transform that will take (0,0,4) to (2,2,4) while leaving the base unchanged.